# How do I compile a pyqt script that uses sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, qt, sqlalchemy, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I tried to use pyinstaller and fbs both to package my python script (just one) into a standalone app. They both built with no errors but when I try running the binary pyinstaller gave this message:

```
/Users/mac/Desktop/mtime/dist/main/main ; exit;
objc[53699]: Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both /Users/mac/Desktop/mtime/dist/main/libQt5Core.5.dylib (0x1081dba80) and /Users/mac/miniconda3/envs/chessapp/lib/libQt5Core.5.9.7.dylib (0x10e377a80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[53699]: Class NotificationReceiver is implemented in both /Users/mac/Desktop/mtime/dist/main/libQt5Widgets.5.dylib (0x1079691b8) and /Users/mac/miniconda3/envs/chessapp/lib/libQt5Widgets.5.9.7.dylib (0x10db051b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x7f8b98f27c80) is not the object's thread (0x7f8b9b08ff30).
Cannot move to target thread (0x7f8b98f27c80)

You might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: cocoa, minimal, offscreen.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem
```

FBS failed as well.

Two slightly unusual things I know I did was I used sqlalchemy in my script and I use conda.

Does anyone know a possible solution? If sqlalchemy doesn't work well with these tools I'm open to using different methods for persistence (is that the term?) for my little script if necessary too.

Im compiling on a mac btw.

Comment: Have you tried to build a simple and basic program, just to ensure that it works? If it does, I'd suggest you to create a stripped down version of your program and if it still does not work, show us its code.

Comment: Good advice. Creating a simple app showed that it doesn't jive well with conda. A venv did the trick. It's cool that pyinstaller could combine the sqlalchemy file as well.

Comment: @squirrels add in an answer it was due to the conda Env messing your build up. That'll mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to conda env messing up the build. Just create a venv is fine (you can use conda to select a python version)

Comment: Also select this as the correct answer with the tick underneath the voting buttons.